# selenium Firefox webdriver python: setting user authentication in setUp()

Tags: python, testing, selenium

I am trying to write a selenium testing case using Python bindings. I am very new to this, so I am really at loss.

My problem: The test is to check basic functionality for wordpress blogs, so logging in is required. I am using unittest, and Im trying to set up user authentication in setUp(), so every time before new test case runs, each cases is logged in as admin.

I have done some researches and tried things without luck. Here is what I have so far.

```
def setUp(self):

    prof_dir = "C:/Python27/python_tests/ff_profile"
    firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(prof_dir)
    firefox_profile.native_events_enables = True
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile)
    self.base_url = "https://blogaddress.com"
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.driver.get(self.base_url + "/wp-login.php")
```

I have saved credentials in profile, so I would expect when webdriver reaches the login page is already filled with credentials. However, it does not do that, and I cannot find a way to set up credentials in setUp(). (I tried quick and dirty way of loggin a user in by sending keys directly but this is just not good)

Is there any good ideas on setting credentials in setUp()?
Thanks for your help.